# Instale SETUP de mi programa C# pero al dar clic en cambiar conexion sale un error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net, app.config

Tengo un boton para cambiar la cadena de conexion y el software en modo Debug si funciona pero al crear el Setup e instalarlo, al querer cambiar la cadena de conexion me sale un error de permisos, es el siguiente y no se como solucionarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: al momento de instalar en el asistente de instalación deberia salirte dos opciones opcion 1 : para todos los usuarios opcion 2 : solo para este usuario. Ahi deberias seleccionar para todos los  usuarios

Comment: No me soluciono el problema

Comment: `Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso`. Parece ser un tema de permisos. Sabes si la aplicación tiene permisos de lectura/escritura a ese directorio? Sabes si el archivo de configuración está siendo utilizado por otro proceso? Cuando le das click a detalles, qué información adicional obtienes?